# Dealing with Soap Security Header using PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I have my PHP code to deal with SOAP, it works fine when I request data from WSDL with no security required. But when I use the same code for a WSDL which requires security header, it shows an error.
The error is: 
 
**Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Client] No WS-Security header found in C:\wamp\www\testing.php:6 Stack trace: #0** 
 
My code is as below.

```
  <?php $requestParams = array(
    'SkuCode' => 'SKUCode'
);

$client = new SoapClient('https://somethinghere.unicommerce.com/services/soap/somethinghere.wsdl');
$response = $client->GetItemType($requestParams);

print_r($response);


?>
```

so where do i need to put the security header? since this code is working fine i believe I only need to add security headers somewhere in this code.

**UPDATE:**

```
<?php 
try {
$security = array(
    'Username'=>'myusername',
    'Password'=>'GSKJHUE87SFJFHSDKF78632BDBFG=',
    'Nonc'=> '7D8SDFKJSDHF678SKDJFHSD==',
    'Created' => '2015-01-03T04:16:42.757Z',
    'UsernameToken' => '876SXVASDFS876BC876CVB876'
);

$header = new SoapHeader('http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd','Security',$security, false);
  $client = new SoapClient('https://myaccountwith.unicommerce.com/services/soap/uniware18.wsdl');
   $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

  $params = new stdClass();
    $params->GetItemType = new stdClass();
    $params->SkuCode = 'ATSC221';

 $result = $client->__soapCall('GetItemType', array($params, null, $header));
    print_r($result);
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
} 
?>
```

The following code outputs the below

```
No WS-Security header found
```

Comment: Is that the real production url? Because that URL outputs an HTML page and not an WSDL (XML) file

Comment: I have changed the URL before posting here because i am not allowed to share the actualy URL, The original URL is actually an XML Format document and not HTML page.

Comment: Contact them and ask  or look in de API docs how WS-Security header need to be generated most likly this some kind of hash.

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953639/connecting-to-ws-security-protected-web-service-with-php  try the SoapClient extension code